# Demeaning Variable data.table way

Tags: r, data.table

I face a problem of demeaning my variable, where a group for a given variable is defined by a logical "or". Consider a following example:

```
set.seed(1)
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
library(readr)

#Generate data:
p1<-rnorm(1000,10)
p2<-rnorm(1000,12)
p12<-rnorm(1000,14)

cat_1<-rep("1",1000)
cat_2<-rep("2",1000)
cat_3<-rep(c("1&2"),1000)
data<-data.table(p=c(p1,p2,p12),cat=c(cat_1,cat_2,cat_3))

mean(data[str_detect(cat,"1"),]$p)
mean(data[str_detect(cat,"2"),]$p)
```

So in this example I want to compute mean (or any other statistic)for a group where 1 is included and then for a group where 2 is included.

Comment: So what is the question? What is the desired output? It seems like you already have a working solution, no? And why do you want to cause your variable to lose its dignity btw?

Comment: What I want is to be able to do that in one shot, i.e. here I have to do that category by category in a sense I do not understand how to "loop" in a data. table way through all the categories, 1,2,3,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I eventually figured out data.table answer:

```
data[,data[str_detect(cat,.BY[[1]]),mean(p)],by=cat]
```

and then take only values for 1 and 2, if somebody knows better way please post it. Fantastic tutorial on tips and tricks of data.table is provided here:

http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/association-rules-beyond-transactional-data/

Answer (score 0):

Making Edits based on your comments:

```
    ##Creating a function
    function_a<- function(data_table,vec) #where vec is a vector of distinct values of category that you want to finally summarize by
    {i=1
    final_summary=NULL
    ##initializing a loop
    for (i in 1:length(vec))
    {data<- data[str_detect(cat,vec[i]),]
    data_aggregate<- data.frame(sum_p=sum(data$p),mean_p=mean(data$p),value_cat=vec[i])
    final_summary<-rbind(final_summary,data_aggregate)
    }
    return(final_summary)
    }
```

With this function now you just need to pass your data table & a vector of distinct values of the category as an argument and it will throw you a data frame of summary of all the stats as an output.
I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: This is not correct, because this will give me means for categories which are defined purely in terms of either 1 or either 2. Just check the example and you will see that your answer does not coincide with:   `mean(data[str_detect(cat,"1"),]$p)`
`mean(data[str_detect(cat,"2"),]$p)`

Comment: as you can see from the question I asked for the data.table solution because I have around 10 million rows and 30 thousands of categories.

Answer (score 0):

```
data[grep("1", cat), mean(p)] # for group 1 included
data[grep("2", cat), mean(p)] # for group 2 included
```

After your comment, what about this:

```
data[, mean(p), by = .(group = grepl("1", cat))]
    [, group := ifelse(group, "1", "2")][]
```

This might be the solution then,

```
tidyr::unnest(data[, .(p, grp = strsplit(cat, "&"))])[, mean(p), by = grp]
```

Only data.table way,

```
data[, .(grp = unlist(strsplit(cat, "&"))), by = p][, mean(p), by = grp]
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I have done, what I need is how to do that in "one shot" i.e. define groups dynamically and then calculate those means.

Comment: I have added another solution, it will be ok, if you have two groups.

Comment: The problem is that this is really a toy example in my "real" example I have n groups and the number of rows is huge.

Comment: In that case, I think you should create a group column and than use that for aggregation. So that you can have control over what combination you need to create group column.

Comment: The problem is that my variable is simultaneously member of two groups and hence I do not really know how to create those groups.

Comment: I am sure there is  a data.table way to do that I just do not know how.

Comment: I have added only the data.table way!!